# javascript function call returns undefined and page continouly loads

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML code as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">ALERT DATA</button>
<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
  {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) 
    {    
           eval(xhttp.responseText);   
        }
  };
 xhttp.open("GET", "sample1.js", true)
 xhttp.send();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Using the AJAX call I am able to call a javascript alert func

```
function callMe(){
 alert("DATA IS 5");
}
document.write(callMe());
```

When I am running this simple HTML file on firefox it gives me "undefined" on the browser. I dont really understand why.I returned ""  from the function callMe() so that removed the "undefined" on the browser but the page seems to be keep on loading . 
Is there anything I am doing wrong ?

Comment: `callMe` returns `undefined`, and that's the value you are writing to the document.

Comment: functions by default return `undefined`, you are probally meaning to do `return "DATA IS 5"`.

Comment: Are you asking why the `alert()` doesn't pause all processing on the page?  If so, it is because the `onreadystatechange` function you provided runs asynchronously from the rest of the page (in "parallel" with it).

Comment: `callMe()` returns nothing. It should return something likes: `callMe() { return "alert('DATA IS 5')"; }` in order to be evaluated.

Comment: @John : actually I need to show the pop up with Yes  and No buttons and do some work on it and I do not want to return anything. So thats why I am returning  " ". And in my browser its showing white screen and thats what I want . But my only concern is the page is still loading so is this ok for an asynchronous call ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method callMe() evaluates to undefined (since it doesn't return anything and alert(...) -being the last command- will evaluate to undefined).

Therefore you will be writing "undefined" to your document.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your support .

I re wrote the js code as follows

```
function callMe(){
 alert("DATA IS 5");
return " ";
}
document.write(callMe());
```

Comment: Thanks thats what I wanted